# drupal 8 image dialog position

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, media

I really hope somebody can help me out with this: I'm designing a Drupal 8 project and I'm using the built-in CKeditor to edit articles. But the image popup renders outside of screen bounds and I can't find how to fix that. There seems to be no way to influence the top parameter of the dialog.

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Matt.

Comment: It's most likely an issue with another JS or CSS file that breaks this.

Answer (score 1):

Im not able to reproduce it on my drupal 8 projects. It might come from your front-end theme. Try to use an administrative theme for edition, like seven.

{yoursite}/admin/appearance
At the bottom of the page check use administrative theme for editing.

If the issue doesn't occur anymore on theme seven, you should start by checking in your front-end (custom?) theme for styles on thoses classes :

```
ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front editor-image-dialog ui-dialog--narrow ui-dialog-buttons
```